# accessing the dom - is there a reader equivalent of Renderer2?

Tags: javascript, angular

I have an angular 5.x app that needs to process payments from an iframe - the callback URL is not part of the angular project, and in fact there are several that might change depending on context.

Some of them are fairly modern and don't present an issue. Others respond to a POST and return raw JSON - in which case I need to get the data directly from the document in the iframe before closing it.

that *requires* (well, hopefully not) accessing:
`elementRef.nativeElement`and from there the `.contentDocument` or `contentWindow.document`, reading the text from there (even though the response is raw JSON, it is loaded in a html iframe, so it gets a document "for free" that I must decouple manually).

So, I do that. It works. But it is not testable. Since I am not reading or writing styles, I don't imagine `Renderer2`  can help me. How can I get the innerText of an element in an iframe without touching the DOM ?

Comment: So i had a similar situation while integration a payment gateway.. As soon as the payment is done the when you get a result to post it back to your application you can use `window.parent.postMessage` Thats how i handled. Its clean and easy no need of accessing dom and all. Just get the required response and post is back to you parent window.

Comment: @Manish - hi Manish. I do not have access to the callback endpoints. Some of them do exactly what you describe and request a callback as a GET. Others request the callback as a POST and POST messages cannot have bodies, so there is no script, no window.parent, etc. The raw JSON _must be_ and is returned in those cases. I must deal with both.

Comment: @Manish - in any case, my problem is not in _processing_ the callback, but in writing test cases for it now that it works.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response.. writing test case will be even trickier.. as gateway is not directly under you control.. good luck with it.. wont be able to help in this case not sure how the stuff is coded and implemented..